# Arduino Uno or php

Tags: c, arduino, arduino-uno

I'm want to grab geolocation coordinates using Google Maps API, send it to my Arduino Uno, and parse the message into a floating numbers array.

I have used `strok()` with `,` as the delimiter but I'm having trouble parsing the SMS message with text and brackets.

```
Sent from your Twilio trial account - (43.39114023431447, -80.40987968444824)(43.387210701009224, -80.41219711303711)(43.38602555366178, -80.38970947265625)
```

I just need to parse the coordinates into a `float` array.

Comment: Does your message always start with "Sent from your Twilio trial account - "? What should your expected result look like? An array containing all floating numbers like this: [43.39114023431447, -80.40987968444824, 43.387210701009224, -80.41219711303711, 43.38602555366178, -80.38970947265625]? Or would you like to create an array for each "pair"/coordinate like [43.39114023431447, -80.40987968444824] and [43.387210701009224, -80.41219711303711] and [43.38602555366178, -80.38970947265625]?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it on my own using strok() function

```
{
     const char *delim  = "(";   //a '(' is the delimiter
     const char *delim1  = ",";
     const char *delim3  = ")";
     char *text;
     char *firstItem;
     char *secondItem;
     char *thirdItem;
     char *fourthItem;
     char *fivethItem;
     char *sixthItem;
     char *seventhItem;
     char *eighthItem;
     text = strtok(password,delim);
     firstItem = strtok(NULL,delim1);
     secondItem = strtok(NULL,delim3);
     secondItem++;
     thirdItem = strtok(NULL,delim1);
     thirdItem++;
     fourthItem = strtok(NULL,delim3);
     fourthItem++;
     fivethItem = strtok(NULL,delim1);
     fivethItem++;
     sixthItem = strtok(NULL,delim3);
     sixthItem++;
     polyX[0] = atof(firstItem);
     polyY[0] = atof(secondItem);
     polyX[1] = atof(thirdItem);
     polyY[1] = atof(fourthItem);
     polyX[2] = atof(fivethItem);
     polyY[2] = atof(sixthItem);
     memset (password,NULL,sizeof(password));
}
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a social network. It is not necesary to say "Hi, michael" in your answer.